# Does two symmetric encryption algorithms return the same result in two different OS and Programming Framework?

Tags: java, .net, encryption, encryption-asymmetric

Simply in .Net  I encrypt the the Id By DES a Symmetric Encryption algorithm and specific Key in .NET . 
I'm wondering could my partner in Java  decrypt just by knowing the name of algorithm and the key ?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks to all answer , I choose the one that first answered though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the implementations are correct, then - yes.

Answer (score 0):

yes he can, that's the point of an algorithm. There are some encryption standards which require additional data, lika padding in RSA, but that does not apply to DES

Comment: by the way. don't use DES, it's not secure anymore, I recommend AES

Answer (score 0):

If you are using same algorithm and same key, you will get the same output. It does not matter which platform you are using.